# I'm trying to test my logger and I'm trying to delete the log file after the integration test

Tags: c#

I'm trying to test my logger and I'm trying to delete the log file after the integration test. But it is getting error saying

What do I have to do to release the file to be deleted.

> file is in use

```
 public void Logger_test()
 {
     //arrange
     string fileName = "InventoryPassword1234.log";
     Trace.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener(fileName, "myListener"));
     //act
     Logger.Info("Hello World", "UnitTestProject1");
     //assert
     Trace.Flush();
     Trace.Listeners.Remove("myListener");
     Assert.IsTrue(File.Exists(fileName));
     //cleanup
     File.Delete(fileName);
 }
```

Comment: have you tried GC.Collect before deleting?

Comment: @Rod if this works for you then mark it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try in this way:

```
public static void Logger_test() {
 //arrange     
 string fileName = "InventoryPassword1234.log";
 TextWriterTraceListener myListener = new TextWriterTraceListener(fileName, "myListener");
 Trace.Listeners.Add(myListener);
 //act
 Logger.Info("Hello World", "UnitTestProject1");
 //assert
 Trace.Flush();
 Trace.Listeners.Remove("myListener");
 myListener.Dispose();
 Assert.IsTrue(File.Exists(fileName));
 //cleanup
 File.Delete(fileName);
}
```

I created the object of TextWriterTraceListener and then disposed it.

Comment: Do I need to have `Trace.Flush()` and remove the listener as well or can I remove those?

Comment: yes, remove and close the file writer/trace listener. Use the Close method of the TextWriterTraceListener class to release the managed resources of a TextWriterTraceListener object. Close method will closes the Writer so that it no longer receives tracing or debugging output and Dispose will Disposes this TextWriterTraceListener object. And Trace.Flush method flushes the output buffer, and causes buffered data to be written to the Listeners. So you need to use in the following way:
        myListener.Flush();
        Trace.Listeners.Remove(myListener);
        myListener.Close();